# Best way to find the matching dependencies?

Tags: node.js, angular, dependencies

Is there any way to find the best match with the dependencies, for example I am using Angular v5.2.0, with some other dependencies I find some issues, now I want to find the dependencies that work with v5.2.0, for that I have search but no success.

Is there any website or source where we can easily get this?

Comment: Every package that you like to install already lists the compatibility with the versions. Check their docs

Comment: I get it well will def. look but I believe it wont work with some external libraries that cause conflicts, like even with Angular they cli, common, rxjs modules separate, while upgrading we have to look for each dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would run `npm ls` which lists all the installed packages with their dependencies (and also their versions) in a tree-structure (dependency tree). There you can see which version of a dependency X is needed/used by Angular v5.2.0.

If you have used a newer version of X in your package.json where you had some issues with, you can downgrade this version to the version which is actually used by Angular v5.2.0.